# Equivalence of definition of squeezed state

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, quantum-optics

With $\hat{a}$ being the annihilation operator for bosons, we can define the displacement operator and squeezing operator as:
$$\hat{D}(\alpha)=\exp(\alpha\hat{a}^{\dagger}-\alpha^{*}\hat{a})\qquad \hat{S}(\xi)=\exp(\frac{1}{2}\xi^{*}\hat{a}^{2}-\frac{1}{2}\xi{\hat{a}^{\dagger}}^{2})$$

In the book *Quantum Optics* written by Scully and Zubairy, the sqeezed coherent state is defined as:
$$|\alpha,\xi\rangle=\hat{S}(\xi)\hat{D}(\alpha)|0\rangle \tag{2.7.10}$$

Exercise **2.5** of this book, says:

> An alternatte definition of a squeezed coherent state is
> $$|\alpha,\xi\rangle=\hat{D}(\alpha)\hat{S}(\xi)|0\rangle $$

I don't figure out how these two definitions are equivalent. Could anyone help to give a rigid proof?

Answer (score 1):

Both of them give squeezed states, but not the same squeezed states (for example, you can calculate and see that their average photon numbers are different)

Comment: Thanks. Could you offer further information on why the second also gives squeezed state?